# How to Deploy a blazor webassembly application that has multi startup projects?

Tags: .net, deployment, blazor-webassembly, repository-pattern

I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly project with multiple startup projects. One project serves as an API, while the other is the UI. andthe project is built using repository pattern  I want to deploy my application and assess its performance. Could someone please assist me with the deployment process?

I have tried searching for relevant information, but unfortunately, I haven't come across any useful resources that can assist me with my query.

Comment: Using 2 startup projects is like starting two webservers.  So, you'll need to deploy them separately.  If you have a registered host, e.g. www.mysite.com, you might deploy your Blazor app to www.mysite.com and your api to subdomain www.api.mysite.com.